# How to get a stack trace for "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL" errors in Chrome/Webkit?

Tags: javascript, webkit, google-chrome-devtools

The cause of this error showing up in the console in Webkit browsers is well-known and described clearly in the error text:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access
>   frame with URL
>   iframed-content-example.com from frame
>   with URL www.example.com. Domains,
>   protocols and ports must match.

But for large sites with many possible pieces of code triggering the error (ads, third-party libraries, site-specific scripts), the error message is not too helpful for tracking down and debugging the line of code that generated the issue.  Is there any way to trigger a stack trace when the cross-domain error occurs?

Comment: Wish I could give this 100 upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is tracked here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88885.

This particular error message shows stack trace in the most recent versions of Chromium.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question and say this is not currently possible.  After checking the source and [Chromium's issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17325#c15), it looks like the lack of stack trace stems from an upstream decision in Webkit to not throw an exception after an unsafe cross-frame access attempt. The decision to keep the error handling deliberately opaque was made based on a security rationale.